# Storing both search and searched term

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, state

So I have stored the current search term in a state using e.target.value, i titled it searchField but when I clear the input value, i cannot use it anymore. I am trying to post a message in the body telling the user that their specific searched term provided no results but i cleared the searchField state. So i need to create another state for searchedTerm in addition to my existing "searchField but unsure how to do it . Feel like I am overlooking something quite simple

On click/submit, can you take the state of searchField and add it into another state (searchedTerm) before setting the searchField to ''

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import request from 'superagent';
import BookList from './BookList'
import Search from './Search'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      bookList: [],
      hasError: false,
      searchField: '',
      value:'',
      loading: false,
      searchResult: ''
    };


  }
  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState ({
      searchField: e.target.value
    })
  }

  

  handleClickBookLookup = (e) => {

    this.setState({
      hasError: false,
      bookList: [],
      loading: true
    })

    request
        .get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/')
        .query({q: this.state.searchField})
        .then ((data) => {
          this.setState({
            bookList: [...data.body.items],
            loading: false,
            searchField: ''
          })
        })
        
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ 
          hasError: true ,
          loading: false,
          searchField: ''
        });
      });

  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Search 
            handleSearch = {this.handleSearch}
            handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}
            handleClickBookLookup = {this.handleClickBookLookup}
            searchField = {this.state.searchField}
          />
        <h1>List Of Books</h1>
        {this.state.hasError && (
          <p>no books found for '________'.</p>
        )}
        <ul>
        {this.state.loading && (
          <p>Loading</p>
        )}
        {this.state.bookList.map((book, i) => {
            return (
              <BookList
                book={book}
              />
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Don't quite understand your approach. If you just want to tell them if there's no results, why not just check for that in the `.then` and *not* wipe their search input if that's the case? `searchField: data.body.items.length > 0 '' : this.state.searchField`

Comment: both your method and the current one already clears the state so there's nothing for the call in the body to pull from. the goal isn't to tell them if theres no results, its to tell them the search term they looked for showed no results. 

" no results for {$searchTerm}"

something like that would be in the body. however in your and my approach, both clear the state. state needs to be cleared to clear the input so there isn't text sitting in the input  and they dont have to remove it to search again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the message to the user, you dont have to clear the state.
However if you want to clear it and still have to show the message. You can do that with a timeout. But since you want to clear the state, message should disappear after some time. You dont to want to keep different states for the same thing, it is ambiguous.

You can add a setTimeout in `then` or `catch` depending on your case. Clear the state after you have shown the message.

```
setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ hasError: false, searchField: '' }) },3000)
```

Comment: Well I dont WANT to clear the state. I am clearing the state to clear out the form input as that's sort of necessary. also from what I have been told, there's a way to do this by having a separate state for each. this is moreso what i am looking at. i dont believe i can use timeout because that will delay the input clearing and will make the message in the body clear as well

Comment: @Pseudo737 when you hit submit for the search query you can add the search query into a different state variable or class variable and use it for showing in the body and it will be update every time when you search new query. You can add it to "handleClickBookLookup"  or "handleSubmit" function where you actually hit for search.

Comment: Can you give me an example. I think i have been at this too long. searchField is being populated by e.target.value , so how do i take it and set it to a new state when its originally coming from e.target.value, do i take the state from the other state? before its set to ''

Comment: @Pseudo737 I have done something here regarding showing the message in body. See if its helpful https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shtern-b7hd4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you mean now. What you should do is copy the search value into a local instance variable of the component. That way, even if you reset the state, their search term is still accessible

I've added comments for the changes I've made:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import request from 'superagent';
import BookList from './BookList'
import Search from './Search'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Keep a local instance variable with their search term in it
    this._searchField = '';

    this.state = {
      bookList: [],
      hasError: false,
      searchField: '',
      value:'',
      loading: false,
      searchResult: ''
    };


  }
  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState ({
      searchField: e.target.value
    });
  }

  

  handleClickBookLookup = (e) => {
    // Update the local variable here
    this._searchField = this.state.searchField;
    this.setState({
      hasError: false,
      bookList: [],
      loading: true
    })

    request
        .get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/')
        .query({q: this.state.searchField})
        .then ((data) => {
          // In here we only reset the state value, NOT the local instance value.
          // This means what they searched is still accessible
          this.setState({
            bookList: [...data.body.items],
            loading: false,
            searchField: ''
          })
        })
        
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ 
          hasError: true ,
          loading: false,
          searchField: ''
        });
      });

  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Search 
            handleSearch = {this.handleSearch}
            handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}
            handleClickBookLookup = {this.handleClickBookLookup}
            searchField = {this.state.searchField}
          />
        <h1>List Of Books</h1>
        {this.state.hasError && (
          // Here, we render the local instance variable
          <p>no books found for {this._searchField}.</p>
        )}
        <ul>
        {this.state.loading && (
          <p>Loading</p>
        )}
        {this.state.bookList.map((book, i) => {
            return (
              <BookList
                book={book}
              />
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Of course be aware that changing `_searchField` won't trigger a re-render, since it's not in the state. Doesn't matter in this use case, but just something to remember.

As a side note, in terms of UX, be careful completely wiping someone's search term(s) when they search. Means if they had a small typo, or want to make a small change to their search like adding or removing a word or changing some spelling, they gotta type it out all over again. It's often better to preserve their search, and give an option to clear it, like how many search boxes have a little cross icon on the right hand side that wipes the search box

Comment: Whoops deleted my original comment. The body still seems to rerender as they type their next search

Comment: I am no expert but anything that changes causes a rerender, so if it's attached to e.target.value and it's a let/var or state. I am going to face this problem, no?

but yes good point about the UX. This is moreso based on me figuring out how to achieve it, its been bothering me for quite some time because I feel there is an easy way to address this that im overlooking

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you can set up a code sandbox that might help clear things up. And no, only changes in state or props cause a re-render in React. Local variables stored under `this` like `this.something` can be changed without causing re-renders

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-browser-ekwi5?file=/src/App.js hopefully this works

Comment: updated file, forgot to save. if you want to test it, search for something like "opsdifjoijoijmoikm" to get no results and then search up a new item

Comment: @Pseudo737 ahh ok I thought the state value only got updated when they searched, didn't see it was tracked in real time. Yeah so as you type it's the state change that was causing the re-render and showing the updated instance variable. The fix is to just update the local variable in the `handleClickBookLookup` function, rather than the on `handleSearch` function. I've updated my code, or you can check the sandbox I updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-archimedes-6ybdw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: awesome that worked! are you able to give me a quick explanation on why that worked. i tried to set a const there to store it but that wasn't accessible from where i was calling for it. i know storing it in state allows it to be accessible but youre not storing it in state. so why is this accessible and where is it stored? and how is it different than a const and state

Comment: @Pseudo737 React class components are just typical Javascript classes. Which are similar to classes in other languages like Java. Inside their functions they have access to a `this` object which refers to itself. Through that it can access its own variables and functions. So by attaching a variable to `this` in the constructor, it is available in the rest of the class. `state` works in the same way, you access it via `this.state`. However state is special in React because of the `Component` your class is extending, which has all the functionality around it, like re-rendering when state changes